# What are the different types of runfiles

Tags: bazel

In the documentation of [DefaultInfo](https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/skylark/lib/globals.html#DefaultInfo), we now can return 3 different "types" of runfiles:

```
runfiles
data_runfiles
default_runfiles
```

I could not find any documentation where the separation between these is and when to use which. Could anyone elaborate in detail?

Answer (score 6):

`data_runfiles` are the files that are added to the runfiles of a binary that depends on the rule via the `data` attribute. `default_runfiles` are the files that are added to the runfiles of a binary that depends on the rule via anything but the `data` attribute. `runfiles` are a shorthand for creating a `DefaultInfo` that has the same set of files acting as both the `data_runfiles` and `default_runfiles`.

Consider the following example involving the `filegroup` rule. (I'm not entirely sure why `filegroup` cares whether or not it is referenced via the `data` attribute, but it does and it makes a simple example.)

```
# BUILD
filegroup(
    name = "a",
    srcs = ["b"],
    data = ["c"],
)
sh_binary(
    name = "bin1",
    srcs = ["bin.sh"],
    deps = [":a"],
)
sh_binary(
    name = "bin2",
    srcs = ["bin.sh"],
    data = [":a"],
)

# bin.sh
ls
```

We find that file `b` is in the runfiles of `:bin2` but not `:bin1`.

```
$ bazel run //:bin1
bin1
bin.sh
c

$ bazel run //:bin2
b
bin2
bin.sh
c
```

Now lets have a look at the `default_runfiles` and `data_runfiles` directly.

```
# my_rule.bzl
def _impl(ctx):
  print(ctx.attr.dep.default_runfiles.files)
  print(ctx.attr.dep.data_runfiles.files)
my_rule = rule(
    implementation = _impl,
    attrs = {"dep": attr.label()},
)

# BUILD
load("//:my_rule.bzl", "my_rule")
my_rule(name = "foo", dep = ":a")


$ bazel build //:foo
WARNING: /usr/local/google/home/ajmichael/playgrounds/runfiles/my_rule.bzl:2:3: depset([File:[/usr/local/google/home/ajmichael/playgrounds/runfiles[source]]c]).
WARNING: /usr/local/google/home/ajmichael/playgrounds/runfiles/my_rule.bzl:3:3: depset([File:[/usr/local/google/home/ajmichael/playgrounds/runfiles[source]]b, File:[/usr/local/google/home/ajmichael/playgrounds/runfiles[source]]c]).
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //:foo up-to-date (nothing to build)
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.194s, Critical Path: 0.00s
```

As you can see, `default_runfiles` contains only `c` while `data_runfiles` contains both `b` and `c`.